# The interaction between TensorFlow Python frontend and its C++ core

Tags: tensorflow

[TensorFlow whitepaper](http://download.tensorflow.org/paper/whitepaper2015.pdf) says that it has a core written in C++. Does it mean that specified computation graph in Python is completely transformed into C++ equivalent code for the execution? If yes, is it possible to extract the generated intermediate code? My use-case is to observe the calls to the cuDNN library for an specified computation graph.

Comment: You can see the intermediate format if you do `print(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def())`. To observe CuDNN calls perhaps you could add some print statements to `tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc`

Comment: Thanks @YaroslavBulatov. If you provide your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the intermediate format if you do `print(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def())`. To observe CuDNN calls perhaps you could add some print statements to `tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc`